# How to host my WCF Service on IIS

Tags: wcf, iis

I want to host my service on IIS and let people from local network use it. Here is my interface:

```
namespace SubscriptionService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ISubsService
    {
        // SOA
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "registerevent/{serviceId}/{name}/{description}")]
        string RegisterEvent(string serviceId, string name, string description);

        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "unregisterevent/{serviceId}/{name}")]
        string UnregisterEvent(string serviceId, string name);

        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "riseevent/{serviceId}/{name}")]
        string RiseEvent(string serviceId, string name);

        // REST
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "events/{token}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        List<EventInfo> EventsList(string token);

        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "subscribe/{token}/{serviceId}/{name}")]
        string Subscribe(string token, string serviceId, string name);

        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "unsubscribe/{token}/{serviceId}/{name}")]
        string UnSubscribe(string token, string serviceId, string name);
    }
}
```

And web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="SubscriptionService.SubsService">
        <endpoint address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="SubscriptionService.ISubsService"></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="rest" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="SubscriptionService.ISubsService" behaviorConfiguration="web"></endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

I need to use both soa and rest methods. Is there something wrong with my config? I tried to add this service on IIS, but it didn't work. I set sitename "my service", path to directory with svc file, host name "myservice" and port. And it didn't work. A was not able to access it even on my local machine.

Comment: did you try browsing the .svc file from InetMgr?

Comment: What does it mean by "didn't work"? Please post error/exception you are getting.

Comment: I get 404 in browser